# Using Docker to mimic an existing Production server vs. deploying Docker containers to production?

Tags: docker, devops

My production server is owned and managed by my company, they are not using a cloud service provider. My initial plan was to use Docker for dev/stage all the way to production so my server environment would always be consistent. But after more research it seems like Docker containers are not really recommended for use in production, but I'm not sure if this is the case Docker is meant to "allow any app to run anywhere". So I'm considering these two options:

1. **Try to mimic my production server as close as possible in Docker containers on dev/stage** *My current assumption* - more restrictive/less consistency, but more stable.
2. **Attempt to deploy Docker containers to production** - My current assumption: this would allow greater flexibility in terms of languages/environments, but at the risk of instability

Are my assumptions correct? Note that my dev/stage servers already closely match my production server, so do I gain any benefit with using Docker if I go with option 1?

Comment: Your info is old. Docker is now widely used in production at companies like eBay, Uber, PayPal, New York Times, ING, ...
https://www.contino.io/insights/whos-using-docker

Answer (score 1):

The second approach would risk environment inconsistency only if the underlying kernel running docker is too different.

If you can (in dev/stage server) have the same Linux kernel as the one used in production, then deploying docker container would ensure a better reproducibility and ease of deployment (you just run the image you built before).
If not, the first approach could be safer, but with a more complex deployment option.